# Could not locate ordinal parameter [0] expecting one of [1]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am getting issues with `Could not locate ordinal parameter [0] expecting one of [1]` with below codes:

```
@Override
        public T getModel(String propertyName, Object value) throws DAOException {
            StringBuilder strQuery = new StringBuilder();
            strQuery.append("from ");
            strQuery.append(getPersistentClass().getSimpleName());
            strQuery.append(" as c where c.");
            strQuery.append(propertyName);
            strQuery.append("=:"+propertyName);
            Query query = getHibernateSession().createQuery(strQuery.toString());
            query.setMaxResults(1);
            query.setParameter(propertyName, value);
            return (T) query.uniqueResult();
        }
```

I have also tried something like below codes but still getting the Could not locate ordinal parameter [0] expecting one of [1]:

```
@Override
    public T getModel(String propertyName, Object value) throws DAOException {
    StringBuilder strQuery = new StringBuilder();
    strQuery.append("from ");
    strQuery.append(getPersistentClass().getSimpleName());
    strQuery.append(" as c where c.");
    strQuery.append(propertyName);
    strQuery.append("=?1 ");
    Query query = getHibernateSession().createQuery(strQuery.toString());
    query.setMaxResults(1);
    query.setParameter(1, value);
    return (T) query.uniqueResult();
    }
```

I tried to change the propertyName to "propertyName" such as:

```
@Override
        public T getModel(String propertyName, Object value) throws DAOException {
            StringBuilder strQuery = new StringBuilder();
            strQuery.append("from ");
            strQuery.append(getPersistentClass().getSimpleName());
            strQuery.append(" as c where c.");
            strQuery.append(propertyName);
            strQuery.append("=:"+propertyName);
            Query query = getHibernateSession().createQuery(strQuery.toString());
            query.setMaxResults(1);
            query.setParameter("propertyName", value);
            return (T) query.uniqueResult();
        }
```

But I am facing a new error `Could not locate named parameter [propertyName], expecting one of [config_for]\"}}"`

May I know how I can fix this ?

Comment: imho the first one should work, although you might need an `SELECT c FROM` instead of just `from` as you are using an alias.